# How to write code in a question or answer?

Tags: support, code-formatting

How to write code in a question/answer on a Stack Exchange site?

Answer (score 10):

Before and after your code block press the <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) key followed by a blank space.

**(Note: Do not mistake Backtick character and key <kbd>`</kbd>  with apostrophe character and key <kbd>'</kbd>)** *Thanks to @middaparka for the advice*

Backtick key is here on most english keyboards:
[image: backtick key]

[image: code block]

[image: markdown]
(see [Markdown Editing Help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page)

Comment: This is a comment to show you that backtick key to mark inline code spans work on comments too: `println('It works on comments too!');`

Comment: And all my life I've been prepending every single line with 4 spaces

Answer (score 1):

Above the text box there is a button with curly braces. Mark your code and push that button.

Answer (score 0):

If you add four spaces before a line, it will become code.  Otherwise you can copy and paste your code into the text box.  Select it, then press the {} button at the top of the form to turn it into code.

Answer (score 0):

It tells you on the right side when you are writing the question.  I believe it is 4 spaces in front of each line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Put it within backticks or indent the lines with four spaces. This information is clearly provided to you when you go to the post-a-question link.